# FirestoreRecyclerAdaptor not showing first item added to firestore

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

I have a fragment called today, in which i get all the tasks with the current day. But, when i add an item to the firestore with the current day, and this is the first task witch is added  to the firestore, the task is now showed in the fragment, when I add the second task is showed, and the third the same. But the first task is never showed, do you know why is doing this?

This is today fragment:

```
public class TodayFragment extends Fragment {
    private View rootView;
    private TodayAdaptor todayAdaptor;

    private ColorDrawable swipeBackgroundRight = new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
    private Drawable iconDelete;


    private FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    private CollectionReference collectionReference;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (getActivity() != null) {
            getActivity().setTitle(R.string.today);
        }

        collectionReference = firestore.collection("Users")
                .document(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                .collection("Tasks");

        iconDelete = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_delete);
        rootView = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_today, container, false);
        RecyclerView recyclerViewToday = rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_today);

        /* create the options for query */
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        String dateFormatted = java.text.DateFormat.getDateInstance(java.text.DateFormat.FULL).format(calendar.getTime());

        Query query = collectionReference.whereEqualTo("date", dateFormatted);
        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Task> options =
                new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Task>()
                        .setQuery(query, Task.class)
                        .build();

        todayAdaptor = new TodayAdaptor(options);
        recyclerViewToday.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerViewToday.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        recyclerViewToday.setAdapter(todayAdaptor);

        new ItemTouchHelper(new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
            @Override
            public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
                if (direction == ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
                    todayAdaptor.deleteTask(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Task deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onChildDraw(@NonNull Canvas c, @NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {


                View itemView = viewHolder.itemView;
                int iconMargin = (itemView.getHeight() - iconDelete.getIntrinsicHeight()) / 2;
                if (dX > 0) {
                    swipeBackgroundRight.setBounds(itemView.getLeft(), itemView.getTop(), (int) dX, itemView.getBottom());
                    iconDelete.setBounds(itemView.getLeft() + iconMargin, itemView.getTop() + iconMargin, itemView.getLeft() + iconMargin + iconDelete.getIntrinsicWidth(), itemView.getBottom() - iconMargin);
                } else {
                    swipeBackgroundRight.setBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
                }
                c.save();

                swipeBackgroundRight.draw(c);
                if (dX > 0) {
                    c.clipRect(itemView.getLeft(), itemView.getTop(), (int) dX, itemView.getBottom());
                } else {
                    c.clipRect(itemView.getRight() + (int) dX, itemView.getTop(), itemView.getRight(), itemView.getBottom());
                }

                iconDelete.draw(c);

                c.restore();

                super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
            }
        }).attachToRecyclerView(recyclerViewToday);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        todayAdaptor.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        todayAdaptor.stopListening();
    }
}
```

This is my adaptor:

```
public class TodayAdaptor extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Task, TodayAdaptor.TodayViewHolder> {

    public TodayAdaptor(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Task> options) {
        super(options);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull TodayViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Task model) {
        holder.todayCheckBox.setChecked(model.isCompleted());
        holder.taskDescription.setText(model.getName());
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public TodayViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.today_item, parent, false);
        return new TodayViewHolder(view);
    }

    public void deleteTask(int position){
        /* save the item to be
          restored if the user want's so
         */
        getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position).getReference().delete();
    }


    class TodayViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private CheckBox todayCheckBox;
        private TextView taskDescription;

        public TodayViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            todayCheckBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.today_item_check_box);
            taskDescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.today_item_task_description);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: you cant see the the first event when there are multiple or you can never see the first event?

Comment: I can't never see the first event.

Comment: I solved, the problem was that my first item was hidden by toolbar.